# Python - How to get input to another code

Tags: python, python-3.x, quandl

I would like to ask you. I need to get quandl input ID to the second line of code (quandl.get(*****)). Is it even possible to do it? Please, can you give me an advice? Thank you so much.

```
instrument = input("Insert quandl ID") 
Ticker1 = quandl.get(**Instrument input here****, start_date="2017-1-1", end_date=datetime.today())
```

I tried this

```
instrument = input("Insert quandl ID")  Ticker1 =
quandl.get(instrument, start_date="2017-1-1", end_date=datetime.today())
```

But this variantion show me warning like thi ->
[Warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYCma.png)

Maybe I have mistake in this part of code?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(22, 15))
ax = plt.subplot(511)
plt.plot(df1[instrument], label='Podkladový instrument', color = "black")
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

Thank you @Primusa

Comment: `Ticker1 = quandl.get(instrument, start_date="2017-1-1", end_date=datetime.today())`?

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are seeing relates to Matplotlib, it has nothing to do with the first two lines of code. Possibly with the second part. Also, it's a a deprecation warning, not an error. Essentially its telling you the way you are doing something will no longer be supported in future versions of Matplotlib. I.e. in future it will result in an error.

What the warning relates to I don't know, I'm not very familiar with Matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you Karl, but I still struggle with problem mentionet above. If I use "instrument input"(Like @Primusa suggested) price charts does not show, but If I use exact quandl ID (CHRIS/CME_CL2) the code work fine. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem is space between instrument and equal (=)

this works `instrument= input("Insert quandl ID")`

Maybe it will help somebody.